# Rounding 64 bit integers to 32 bit integers

Tags: c, rounding, int64, int32

I have a function that does rounding operation as shown below. It takes 64bit integer as input and gives 32bit integer as output. While converting, a factor of 0x40000000 is being added to the input. What is the reason behind it?

```
int rounder(long long int in)
{
  INT64 out;
  if ((in >> 32) == 0x7FFFFFFF)
    out = in;
  else
    out = (INT64)0x40000000 + in; 
  out = out >> 31; 
  return (INT32)out;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `var` getting used

Comment: please show the definitions of INT64 and INT32, and the sample input and output you get. Preferably post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff..Hi, I have Edited the code

Comment: The rounding is incorrect for negative values.

Comment: Cast in `out = (INT64)0x40000000 + in;` is not needed.

Comment: @M.M INT64 is nothing but long long int and INT32 is a normal integer(int). The input used is 31644033252 and got 15 as the output correspondingly.

Comment: "Rounding 64 bit integers" is a misnomer as the parameter is `long long int`.  Today, `long long int` is overwhelmingly 64-bit, but that is not certain for the future.  Plan for _someday_ 128 `long long` possibilities.  If one wants 64-bit integer, use `int64_t`.

Comment: `return (INT32)out` is incorrect for `out` values near `LLONG_MAX`.  Much wrong with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with some smaller numbers, because they're easier!

Using conventional rounding, x.49999... or less should round down to x, x.50000... or more should round up to (x+1).

(There are [lots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) of different rounding methods, but this is the one most learn at school.)

Whenever you do integer division (or conversion of a floating point value to an integer), you simply throw away the fractional part.  Hence:

```
6/2 == 3.0  --> 3
5/2 == 2.5  --> 2
```

A neat 'trick' is to add half-the-divisor (1, in this case) before division.  As if by magic, you get the right rounding!  eg:

```
6/2  becomes  (6+1)/2  == 7/2 == 3.5  --> 3
5/2  becomes  (5+1)/2  == 6/2 == 3.0  --> 3
```

You can see why this works by looking at it this way:

```
 5/2  becomes  (5+1)/2  ==   5/2 + 1/2
13/6  becomes (13+3)/6  ==  13/6 + 3/6   == 13/6 + 1/2
```

You're adding half to the real answer.  Anything less than x.5 will still be less than x+1 so will still round down, anything of x.5 or more will become x+1 or more so will round up.

Now to your actual question:
This idea works with all divisors; you're shifting down by 31, which is the same as dividing by 2^31.  So 'half-the-divisor' is 2^30, or 0x40000000.

Beware: as others have noted, this 'trick' only works for positive numbers (you need to subtract if it's negative, but it's a can of worms).

There is a lot to consider in this topic; it's not simple to get your head around.  As ever, try some easy examples for yourself and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The input appears to be a 64-bit fixed point number with 31 fraction bits.  The 0x40000000 value is added to round the number up if it has a fractional part >= 0.5.  The `if` is used to avoid possible overflow when factoring in the rounding.

Comment: Hi, your answer seems to be helpful to me. can you explain in detail?

Comment: Fixed point numbers are integers where you have an imaginary "decimal point" (actually a "binary point" ;-) between two defined bits. Bits left of it are the integer part, bits right of it are the fractional part.